# Javascript document.lastModified returning US Date format

Tags: javascript

using `document.lastModified` in javascript returns a date in the format "mm/dd/yyyy". Is there anyway to have it return the date in ISO or sensible date order (yyyy-mm-dd or dd-mm-yyyy) instead or do I have to convert the string to a date and then convert it back to a proper display?

Comment: `var lastModified = new Date(document.lastModified);`?  The docs seem to indicate that the property is simply a string

Comment: I don't think there's a way to change it without doing the conversion you mentioned (and presented in other people's solutions).  It's what's specified in the HTML5 draft: "MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm:ss", in the user’s local time zone.: http://w3c.github.io/html/dom.html#dom-document-lastmodified

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[From MDN web docks](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/lastModified#Example_2_Transforming_lastModified_into_a_Date_object) you can create a Date Object like:

```
var oLastModif = new Date(document.lastModified);
```

Now with the Date Object you can modify with [Intl.DateTimeFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DateTimeFormat)

```js
var myDate = new Date(document.lastModified);

console.log('toISOString', myDate.toISOString());

myNewDate = new Intl.DateTimeFormat(
            "de-AT",
            {year: "numeric", month: "numeric", day: "numeric"}
).format(myDate).replace(/\./g, '-');

console.log('Intl.DateTimeFormat', myNewDate);

document.querySelector('.one').innerHTML = myDate.toISOString();
document.querySelector('.two').innerHTML = myNewDate;
```

```html
<div class="one"></div>
<div class="two"></div>
```

Comment: I will give that a shot (though I am doing this inside an HTML document, so I'll have to do document.write...

Comment: @lbutlr I've update the answer. use `innerHTML` in this case.